# Proper ways to write Makefile for a relatively large C program?

Tags: c, makefile

Program tree:

```
├── Makefile
├── foo
├── lib
│   └── foo.h
└── src
    └── foo.c
```

I am wondering if there are proper ways to write the Makefile to compile a C program like this structure? Like putting all .c files inside `src` folder whilst keeping all header files in `lib` folder.

Tried to write Makefile for it but it did not work as expected... And also, I was trying to make .o files in `build` folder but I'm not sure how to do that. If I have many files from both src and lib folder, what's the proper way to link them together?

My Makefile:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Werror -Wall
TARGET := foo
LIBDIR := lib
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := build
LIBS = -Ilib
.PHONY: all
.PHONY: clean

all: ${TARGET}

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c,$(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/ *.h)
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LIBS} ${SRCDIR}/${TARGET}.c

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET)
```

Showing up errors when I do `make`

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo.c,lib/foo.h', needed by 'foo'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Using `lib` for headers is an unuusual choice.

Comment: To solve your *specific* problem, replace the comma in your prerequisite list with a space. Then I suggest you start with all of your sources and headers in the working directory, and write a makefile for that. Once that's working perfectly you can introduce other directories like `src`, `lib` and `build`. And if you want object files (e.g. `foo.o`) you must not compile sources directly to executables.

Comment: Read the documentation, some tutorials, and consider `VPATH` for your sources. Look at other project's Makefiles.

Comment: did you look at cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need to replace the comma with a space in `$(TARGET): what,ever`

The best way to make these applications would be to add instructions on compiling for each object or library you introduce

Such as adding files.o

```
files.o: files.c files.h
   // Compile command
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the useful advice! I ended up with writing the part like this:

```
%.o: ${LIBDIR}/%.h
    mkdir ${BUILDDIR}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c ${LIBDIR}/${TARGET}.h -o ${BUILDDIR}/${TARGET}.o
$(TARGET): $(TARGET).o 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LIBS} ${SRCDIR}/${TARGET}.c -o $(TARGET)
```